# line 8, in speak voiceEngine.getProperty("rate", 100) TypeError: getProperty() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pyttsx3

This is my code

```py
import pyttsx3

# This function is used to process text and speak it out
def speak (lis):
    voiceEngine = pyttsx3.init() 
    voiceEngine.getProperty("rate", 100)
    #voice_id = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\IVONA 2 Voice Brian22" 
    #voiceEngine.setProperty('IVONA 2 Brian - British English male voice [22kHz]', voice_id ) 
    voiceEngine.say (lis)
    voiceEngine.runAndWait() 
    voiceEngine.stop


speak(lis = "Hello i am alpha, your personal digital assistant. how may i be of your assistance")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for [`pyttsx3.ening.Engine.getProperty`](https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html?highlight=getProperty#pyttsx3.engine.Engine.getProperty) it looks like you're giving it too many arguments:

> getProperty(name : string) → object
>
> Gets the current value of an engine property.
> Parameters:    name – Name of the property to query.
> Returns:   Value of the property at the time of this invocation.

You are giving it an extra parameter: `100`. You should only be providing the name of the property you are looking to access: `voiceEngine.getProperty("rate")`.

Unless you were looking to use [`pyttsx3.engine.Engine.setProperty`](https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html?highlight=getProperty#pyttsx3.engine.Engine.setProperty) which does take a second value for the value to set the property to.